# wso2 mashup server versus wso2 gadget server

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to decide how to choose between the WSO2 Gadget Server and WSO2 Mashup Server.

There seems to be quite a lot of overlap in their functionality.

When and how would you choose between the two servers?  Are there circumstances where you may need both servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking through various literature, such as [gadget server data sheet](http://wso2.com/wp-content/datasheets/GS.pdf) and [mashup server data sheet](http://wso2.com/wp-content/datasheets/MS.pdf), here are my conclusions:

1) Mashup server is used for "pulling" content from various different sources (e.g. web pages, rss, data services, web services) that may be internal or external to the organisation and exposing that content in various formats (e.g. web pages, email, im, files). See the diagram on page 2 of the Mashup Server data sheet.

2) Gadget server is used for creating user dashboards of gadget that may be internal or external to the organisation.  Gadgets can be created to exposed internal application services.  In this respect, Gadget server is like a lightweight portal server.  See the diagram on page 2 of the Gadget Server data sheet.

3) Mashup server can expose pulled in content as gadgets that can be consumed by the Gadget server.